# How to change the default background colour for mapView.callout using react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps

I am trying to change the background color of the callout, but the background color is not effecting to the total view.

Here is the screenshot of what I have:

[image]

I want the backgroundColor to encompass the full tooltip.

Here is my code:

```
<MapView.Callout
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 40,
              backgroundColor: '#107B67',
              borderRadius: 10,
              zIndex: 10
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
              }}
            >
              <Text>logkjbkb</Text>
            </View>
          </MapView.Callout>
```

How can I set the backgroundColor to the whole callout?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the 'tooltip' prop on the Callout component to true.

```
<MapView.Callout
    tooltip={true}
    style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#107B67',
        borderRadius: 10,
        zIndex: 10
     }}
  >
</MapView.Callout>`
```

Prop:
**tooltip**

Type:
**Boolean   false**

If *false*, a default "tooltip" bubble window will be drawn around this callouts children. If *true*, the child views can fully customize their appearance, including any "bubble" like styles.

Here is the reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/callout.md

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (if you want to use default bubble)

- Create a custom callout with style `CustomCallout` View with style `{margin: -30; padding: 30; backgroundColor: "Your favorite color"}`
- Use it inside Callout `<Callout> <CustomCallout/> </Callout>`

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapCustomStyle = [ { "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#242f3e" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#746855" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#242f3e" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative.locality", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#263c3f" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#6b9a76" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#38414e" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#212a37" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9ca5b3" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#746855" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#1f2835" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f3d19c" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#2f3948" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#17263c" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#515c6d" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#17263c" } ] } ]
```

and Finally in mapView

```
use customMapStyle= {mapCustomStyle}
```

Thanks to https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ site I have generated above code from this side